# bootstrap carousel pause not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm unable to invoke the 'pause' function on the Bootstrap (3.0.2) carousel. I've tried every way I can think of to refer to the carousel instance, but - no errors, no pause.

```
<script>
    var stepIndex = 3;
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    });
    $('#carousel-couples').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        stepIndex--
        console.log("carousel stepping", stepIndex);
        if (stepIndex == 0) {
            console.log("supposedly pausing carousel");
            $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling pause on a carousel while its sliding does not seem to work.  Instead use the `slid.bs.carousel` event runs once the slide has finished the transition and then your `pause` should work.

```
$('#carousel-couples').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: well, that did the trick - though I certainly did try it at some point in my struggles, don't know why it didn't work then. Thanks!